# How to disable Android Navigation at res/navigation/nav_graph.xml

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have deleted the Fragment I created and its layout as I don't need it anymore.

But the Fragment keeps coming back except its layout (that is why I'm getting a missing layout.)

I saw it in the res/navigation/nav_graph.xml.
So I decided to delete the whole nav_graph.xml

On my third try, I included the deletion of the following implementation setup:

- ***implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2'***
- ***implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2'***

But these two returned as well..

What is the trick of totally deleting them for good?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the fragment in the activity xml that contains

```
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```

And if you still having the navgraph.xml, remove the startDestination property.

So then, select File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate Cache & Restart